# Laravel 5.1 Validation not ignoring unique on update

Tags: php, validation, laravel

Hi I'm having trouble getting laravel to ignore an unique identifier rule when updating. I've tried using $member->id, $id ,'.$member->id ,'.$id etc

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
      'first'  => 'required|min:2',
      'last'   => 'required|min:2',
      'mobile' => ['required','regex:^(\+614)+([0-9 {8})$^','unique:members,mobile,$id'],
   ];
}
```

Comment: I eneded up adding the validation to the controller only for the update function

    `$this->validate($request, [  
    'name' => 'required|min:3',  
    'email' => ['required', 'email', 'regex:^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$^',"unique:users,email,".$user->id],  
    'password' => 'min:8|confirmed'  
    ]);`

Answer (score 1):

To use the `$id` variable in the string, [double quote it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

```
['required','regex:^(\+614)+([0-9 {8})$^',"unique:members,mobile,$id"]
//                                        ^                         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are inside a [Form Request Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation), you should be able to do this:

```
['required','regex:^(\+614)+([0-9 {8})$^','unique:members,mobile,'.$this->get(id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Requests` for `form validation` , you can do like this for unique validation :

> 'unique:table_name ,
>   unique_column,'.$this->route->getParameter('parameter').',primary_key'

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
      'first'  => 'required|min:2',
      'last'   => 'required|min:2',
      'mobile' => 'required | regex:^(\+614)+([0-9 {8})$^| unique:members,mobile,'.$this->route()->getParameter('id').',id',
   ];
}
```